# An explanation of Kendo MVVM and MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm

So,

I would really like to see if I can get some sort of explanation here.  I am currently developing and application in asp.net MVC and I continue to run into the situation of needing to create dynamic pages with a number of AJAX calls on the page to update data, reload tables, and other such tasks.  I don't know a lot about MVVM technology but I have done some reading and tried some examples on Kendo MVVM.  I *really* like how you can bind data to a view model on the front end and perform a number of actions while manipulating a client side model. However this is MVC so ultimately I do have to update data server side and have the client side changes reflected on a server side model.

I have read a couple articles that mention that these are two different technologies that aren't intended to be used together, however I really feel that it would reduce development time and complexity if I could somehow get these technologies to play nice together.  Is it possible to perform data manipulations and update client side tables and data presentation with MVVM and then submit the client side changes to the server via a post method?  I am having some difficulty tracking down how to do this.  If this is not possible or is a bad development practice, could I get an explanation why this isn't possible?

Comment: "I have read a couple articles" Unsubscribe those blogs now. They provide terrible information.

Comment: Also, the MVC helpers from Kendo will hurt you in the long run. I would stick to standard JavaScript API, at least for the grids, listviews and all those big controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are two different technologies, but there's absolutely no reason to not use them in conjunction with each other in this particular case.

Think about how you're using MVC currently, you have your Models, which are strongly typed and there to aid in displaying data on your View. So let's say that I wanted to display a car. Normally I would just include the following code on the View that I wanted to display the data on.

```
@model Car
```

Now think about how would you achieve that by using JavaScript...

It's simple, just display the data on the view as JSON, and then consume it with JavaScript...

I've written a simple extension method that you can use to achieve this.. add the class below to your project...

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString JsonFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, TModel model)
    {
        return JsonFor(helper, model, Formatting.None);
    }

    public static IHtmlString JsonFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, TModel model, Formatting formatting)
    {
        string jsonModel = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
            Formatting = formatting
        });

        return new HtmlString(jsonModel);
    }
}
```

Then in your `View`....

```
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var carData = @(this.Html.JsonFor(this.Model));
        function Car(car) 
        {
            var self         = this;
            self.numberPlate = ko.observable(car.NumberPlate || '');
            self.name        = ko.observable(car.Name        || '');
            self.model       = ko.observable(car.Model       || '');
            self.yearMade    = ko.observable(car.YearMade    || '');
            self.color       = ko.observable(car.Color       || '');
            self.fuel        = ko.observable(car.Fuel        || '');
        }
    `
        ko.applyBindings(new Car(carData));
    </script>
}
```

> Is it possible to perform data manipulations and update client side tables and data presentation with MVVM and then submit the client side changes to the server via a post method?

Yes.

All you need to do is post the data to your Controller Action using AJAX.

Comment: Can you add the proper way to do the ajax post when using kendo mvvm so I can mark this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I've been down this road and my experience it takes some carving up of Kendo in order for it to play nice with MVC. It did a good job for displaying get data, but post and puts needed work. This also was a year ago, not sure if they've improved binding transactions to MVC project.

But if you're interested in model binding to controls, I'd recommend trying out knockout. Here's a great SPA app to try out...

http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/introduction/knockoutjs-template